# calculate data within foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have pulled out data from my database of eps of companies for last 2 years I wanted to sum up eps by using a small formula what happened here is I pulled out data in the form of array now I want to put formula like this `

```
`

$curr_eps - $old_eps / $old_eps * 100;
```

With the out put I am getting I am unable to put formula for every company and get separate calculated values

My output data is like this

```
foreach($data3 as $key => $pr_data) {
            $prof_data[] = $pr_data;
        }
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [eps] => -0.28
            [year] => 2015
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [eps] => 3.33
            [year] => 2014
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [eps] => 0.90
            [year] => 2015
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [eps] => 0.81
            [year] => 2014
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [eps] => 1.05
            [year] => 2016
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [eps] => 3.71
            [year] => 2015
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [eps] => 1.61
            [year] => 2016
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [eps] => -0.49
            [year] => 2015
        )

)
```

I am wondering to put data here as of without loop this is the output coming on 
          $prof_data[] = $data3 //This contains array value;
           Out Put`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [eps] => -0.28
                    [year] => 2015
                    [company_id] => 348
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [eps] => 3.33
                    [year] => 2014
                    [company_id] => 348
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [eps] => 0.90
                    [year] => 2015
                    [company_id] => 351
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [eps] => 0.81
                    [year] => 2014
                    [company_id] => 351
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [eps] => 1.05
                    [year] => 2016
                    [company_id] => 356
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [eps] => 3.71
                    [year] => 2015
                    [company_id] => 356
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [eps] => 1.61
                    [year] => 2016
                    [company_id] => 366
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [eps] => -0.49
                    [year] => 2015
                    [company_id] => 366
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Now can anybody help me out to solve this issue I am not good while making to understand what I wam trying to do please let e know if you have queries

Comment: Can anyone please rephrase this question in easy english.

Comment: @Usman Khan yes i m also not getting your question please simply explain it

Comment: i was expecting this lol sorry mate simple is that I want to put formula on company company data each company have 2 paired data and I want to get percentage as you can see all data is within the loop

Comment: @BunkerBoy let me explain more let me update my question

Comment: @BunkerBoy Check now is it helpfull

Comment: how do I sum each 2 values within loop?

Comment: @Usman Khan data you got from db ?

Comment: yes I got from data base

Comment: Wanted to play like this [0][eps] => -0.28-  [1][eps] * 100

Comment: @ Usman Khan show that $data3 array and $curr_eps - $old_eps / $old_eps * 100; is assigned in which key ?

Comment: really still not getting your question show your code what you have tried and your desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you can perform calculation as

```
foreach($data3 as $data){
   $net = $currenteps - $data['eps'];
}
```

You haven't defined what are the currenteps and oldeps, however using $data['eps'] and $data['year'], you can access each eps value and respective year of array